# How do I associate key events with rows of a TreeGrid in dojo?

Tags: dojo, onkeyup, treegrid

I am trying to delete a row on pressing the delete key. However, I am unable to connect individual rows to a key listener. I tried using dojo.connect(row1, "onkeyup", myHandler) to connect a particular row to a custom handler, but the handler never gets called. Is there some other way of doing this? Does the TreeGrid support key events or will I have to get the dom nodes and connect event handlers to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go about it from a different angle. `dojox.grid.TreeGrid` itself has an `onKeyUp` event that would be useful. It detects any key being released when the grid itself is focused. You could attach a handler to the entire TreeGrid, then get the selected row, and delete it with that information. Something like the following:

```
dojo.connect(registry.byId("grid"), "onKeyUp", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 46) { // The keycode for the delete key is 46
        var selectedRow = this.selection.getSelected(); // Get selected item
        // Do your deletion here.
    }
}
```